# CUPS 1.7.5 & Google Could Print - Zebra LP2844 Not Printing

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, cups

I am running a CUPS server on a Raspberry pi, I have now shared the printer with Google cloud print. In theory everything should work. However as soon as I start to use google cloud print it does not want to print.

I send the job to the printer, the job is created and CUPS sees the job

It never prints though, after checking the jobs CUPS has marked it as completed. Can anyone offer any assistance as to what to check next?

I have checked the logs and there seem to be no errors

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you created a pdf or file printer, or a different printer to test if the cloud printing is working at all?